# Equivalent metrics give the same topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> **Definition**
>
> If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are distance in $X$ then we say that they are equivalent iff and only if there exist $\alpha,\beta>0$ such that
> $$
> \alpha\cdot d_1(x,y)\le d_2(x,y)\le\beta\cdot d_1(x,y)
> $$
> for any $x,y\in X$.
>
> **Theorem**
>
> Two metric are equivalent if and only if they give the same topology

If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent then
$$
\alpha\cdot d_1(x,y)\le d_2(x,y)\le\beta\cdot d_1(x,y),\,\,\text{and}\,\,\frac{1}\beta d_2(x,y)\le d_1(x,y)\le\frac{1}\alpha\cdot d_2(x,y)
$$
and so using this inequality I tried to prove that for any $d_1$-ball there exist a $d_2$-ball that is contained in the first and vice versa. Unfortuately I don't be able to do this and then I don't be able to prove that if two metric give the same topology they are equivalent. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: The usual definition of equivalent metrics is different and it is equivalent to the fact that the metrics generate the same topology. But your definition of equivalent metrics is not the usual one.  Where did you find this definition?

Comment: I found it in the text "Analysis on Manifolds" by James Munkres and then in Wikipedia: could you give me your definition?

Comment: I'm curious about it!

Comment: I ddidn't know that Munkres defines it this way. It is not standard. Page 184 of Dugundgi's 'Toplogy' has the standard definition: $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent if for every open ball $B_{d_1}(x,r)$ in the first metric and for any $y$ in this ball there exists $s>0$ such that $B_{d_2}(y,s) \subseteq B_{d_1}(x,r)$ and for every open ball $B_{d_2}(x,r)$ in the second metric and any $y$ in it there exists $s>0$ such that $B_{d_1}(y,s) \subseteq B_{d_2}(x,r)$ . This is true iff the metrics generate the same topology. Munkre's definition is suitable for metrics generated by norms on vector space.

Comment: Se also https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquivalentMetrics.html

Comment: Your condition is often called "strong equivalence". A more systematic name is "Lipschitz equivalence". This condition is however strictly stronger than "the two metrics induce the same topology" (which is the usual notion of equivalence of metrics).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Okay, I understand. Anyway is true that we can claim that two norms are equivalent if any ongly if the generate the same topology?

Comment: Yes, for _norms_ being (Lipschitz) equivalent and inducing the same topology are identical conditions. (Identical in the sense that one holds if and only if the other holds. I refrained from using the word "equivalent" there because - well, make a guess ;)

Comment: Yes, certainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent, can you find relationships between $d_1$-balls and $d_2$-balls?

The converse is false: The discrete metric and the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb{Z}$ give the same topology (the discrete one) yet they are not equivalent.

Comment: I understand the you first hint. But for your second statement what can you say what about is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852113/equivalent-metrics-generate-the-same-topology)?

Comment: There is no contradiction. The implication: Two metrics generate the same topology implies the two metrics are equivalent is false. The other implication is true and is the one your link answers.

Comment: Okay. However could you explain better your counterexample, please?

Comment: What don't you understand about it? You have to show that discrete and Euclidean metric are not equivalent and they both induce the discrete topology.

Comment: It is not clear to me that the discrete metric generate euclidean topology.

Comment: The Euclidean topology on $\Bbb{Z}$ is discrete since singeltons are open (consider balls with radius $1/2$).

Comment: Yes, I understand.